# Genetic programming: Can we get multiple bit output from each individual(tree) if we provide 5 bit input?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, genetics, deap

I want to create population of trees using genetic programming. I am using deap python framework. My trees are based on combination of different logic gates and some terminals.
I want to provide each tree/individual 5 bit input and want to get 32 bit output from each tree. I will calculate fitness from these 32 bits.
Issue: When I provide 5 bit input then Each tree evaluates to single bit output as it is based on logic gates. Is there any way I design the individuals in such a way that they provide me 32 bit output whatever the size of input is ?

Possible approach 1 : Run 5 bit input 32 times . But that will always produce the same same output bits. And I don't want to use random in terminal because I want to produce same output if the input is same.
2: get the output from each node in the tree  : But don't know how to do it in deap. Also the number of nodes vary in each individual.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I think that if I provide 128 bit binary value to one tree (made of and/or/not/xor gates etc) and do bitwise operation on each gate then I might get 128 bit output.